# mantain a sum in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

this is my code

```
def width2colspec(widths):
    tupleback = []
    a=0
    for w in widths:
        b=a+w
        tupleback.append((a,a+w))
        a=b
    return tupleback
```

eg:

```
widths=[15,9,50,10]
width2colspec(widths)
```

Result:

```
[(0, 15), (15, 24), (24, 74), (74,84)]
```

(first one always has to be a zero)

It works and all(maybe not very elegant tho)

To practice I tried to convert it into a list comprehension one liner but i couldn't make it work, closest i got was this.

```
widths=[15,9,50,10]
colspecs=list((widths[i],widths[i]+widths[i+1]) for i in range(len(widths)-1))
```

result:

```
[(0, 15), (15, 24), (9, 59), (50,60)]
```

(its not maintaining the sum trough the loop)

So my question is, is it possible?

Comment: You would have to use the walrus operator. It will be confusing, don't bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this as a pure list comprehension, but it involves a lot of re-computation, so I wouldn't recommend actually doing it this way.

Start by building a list of all the sums (note that this is re-summing the same numbers over and over, so it's less efficient than your original code that keeps a running sum):

```
>>> [sum(widths[:i]) for i in range(len(widths)+1)]
[0, 15, 24, 74, 84]
```

and then iterate over that to produce your list of tuples:

```
>>> [tuple([sum(widths[:i]) for i in range(len(widths)+1)][i:i+2]) for i in range(len(widths))]
[(0, 15), (15, 24), (24, 74), (74, 84)]
```

Note that we're now re-computing all those sums *again* because we didn't assign the original list to a variable.

Comment: ugh yes that doesn't exactly screams readability, but you actually did it, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.8 or later, you can use an assignment expression (utilizing the walrus operator `:=`) to do this in a single list comprehension. I'm "cheating" a little by initializing `last` via a default argument, but this isn't strictly necessary (I just wanted to make it a "one-liner").

```
def width2colspec(widths, last=0):
   return [(last, last := last+width) for width in widths]
```

I don't find it *that* confusing, to be honest.

Comment: this one is pretty good also, but i marked the other answer cause uses LC, thanks!